# Forward the request to non struts 2 action from struts2 action?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2

I have legacy appication which is using proprieatary framework which is more or less like struts 1.2.Now we have started
using struts 2. At lot of places i am submitting the html form to old actions from jsp. What i want is first request goes
to my new  struts 2 action and then i forward the request to my legacy action from there so that i get all source request paramters in destination legacy action.I know there is result type
redirect(as mentioned below) but that wont forward the source request paramters to legacy action.

```
@Result(name = "displayCustomer",
        location = "legacyAction.do", type = "redirect")


@Action("display-customer!displayCustomer")
  public String displayCustomer() {
    return "displayCustomer";
  }
```

I did not find any type as "forward" similar to redirect. I am not sure how to forward the request to non struts 2 action from struts 2
action?

Comment: The default response type is a forward. Why do you want to go to an action first?

Comment: So that down the line if i want to converts those legacy action to struts 2 action i dont have modify  jsps/view.

Comment: You said default response type is forward, does it mean i don't have to mention type = "redirect" in result annotation. In that case all request parameters will be forwarded to my legacy action.Is it?

Comment: @Dave i tried just giving @Result(name = "displayCustomer",
        location = "legacyAction.do") to forward request to legacy action but server does not start up?

Comment: Response doesn't have nothing that prevents to redirect to the action whether it legacy or not most of the adjustments made to mace it compatible to the objects that not on the value stack. May be the choice to chain legacy actions with the legacy plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply forward the control to respective page based on your result type for example **SUCCESS**.You can use **chain** result type for executing two different action at one time.

It will look like this:

**using XML configuration**

```
    <action class="your_action_path" name="your_action_name" method="your_target_method">
                <result type="chain">your_legacy_action</result>
    </action>

     //Then your_legacy_action_mapping here

<action class="your_legacy_action_path" name="your_legacy_action_name" method="your_target_method">
                <result>your_target_success_page</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: I think action chaning is fr forwarding the request from struts 2 action to another struts 2 action not to legacy action. I think for forwarding the request to legacy action we just nedd disptcher

Answer (score 0):

in struts2 default result type is configured as 'dispatcher'. which 'forwards' the request.
try setting the type="dispatcher". Check your struts configuration whether 'dispatcher' result type has been configured properly. It should look like something below.

```
<result-types>
   <result-type name="dispatcher" default="true"
                class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult" />
</result-types>
```

Comment: i am using annotation. Should it be @Result(name = "displayCustomer", location = "legacyAction.do", type="dispatcher") ?

Comment: yes. Check your struts configuration (struts.xml) just to make sure you have the result type registered as shown above.